# How to search for the certain filename in all subfolders within for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have the following script that renames files in the directory according to the list in file opac_one-hit.log

```
@ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
    FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims=;" %%G IN ( opac_one-hit.log) DO (
    ren %%G %%H
    )
    pause
```

In order to start my script should be located in the same directory where opac_one-hit.log is located. How to build search function in my for loop in order to find the opac_one-hit.log in subfolders and not to copy the script to that subfolder every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested:

```
@ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
    for /r %%# in ("opac_one-hit*.log") do (
      FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,3 delims=;" %%G IN ( "%%~f#" ) DO (
        ren %%G %%H
      )
    )
    pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the folder(s) where the file is with:

```
for /f %%A in ('dir /s /b "c:\basedir\opac_one-hit.log"') do echo %%~dpA
```

where `basedir` is the location to start the recursive search (to avoid searching the whole disk).

If you are sure, there is just one of your files, set a variable instead of `echo`ing it or use the below version. Also use the below, to process *every* found `opac_one-hit.log`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /s /b "c:\basedir\opac_one-hit.log"') do  (
  FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,3 delims=;" %%G IN ("%%A") DO (
    echo ren "%%G" "%%H"
  )
)
pause
```

REM remove the `echo`, when the rename commands are correct.